# Getting 'Figure(..x..)' when drawing quantum circuit with qiskit “mpl” output mode

Tags: quantum-computing, qiskit

I am just starting with Quantum Computing and I tried the following code.

```
from qiskit import *

qr = QuantumRegister(2)
cr = ClassicalRegister(2)

Qc = QuantumCircuit(qr,cr)

print ('This is the initial state')
print(Qc.draw(output = 'mpl'))
print ('')
```

The problem I am facing is with drawing the circuit. When use qc.draw() it gives me a line representation of the circuit and its good enough for me to see what is on it. But when I put output='mpl' I am getting the following results.

This results in

```
This is the initial state
Figure(142.949x204.68)
```

I have been using spyder for all my programming but I also tried the same thing in jupyter and the result was the same.  What is this Figure(.............) and where can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

Hey I tried this with a simple change in the draw command

```
from qiskit import *

qr = QuantumRegister(2)
cr = ClassicalRegister(2)

Qc = QuantumCircuit(qr,cr)

print ('This is the initial state')
Qc.draw(output = 'mpl')
```

Output:

[image]

If this didn't work try installing visualization tools

Answer (score 0):

When you use 'mpl', the output is a figure and not a string that you can print. Remove print and try:

```
print ('This is the initial state')
Qc.draw('mpl').show()
```

The output is:

This is the initial state

[image: output]

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the reply. I tired doing what you said and I got the following error: 

<ipython-input-2-7141ef2bc8ad>:9: UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
  qc.draw('mpl').show()

Comment: Are you using Jupyter Notebooks? If yes, then remove .show() and let the last line of the cell be Qc.draw()

Comment: I am using Spyder.

Comment: Try to use `pip install qiskit[visualization]`. If it still does not work, you might need to change the backend in Spyder settings.